# Unable to get started with apache tomcat

Tags: java, apache, tomcat7

I have started learning Servlets, so I downloaded the apache tomcat 7.x zip file(core--> zip) from [here](http://tomcat.apache.org/download-70.cgi). I extracted it to my directory (D:), then I have just set up the `JAVA_HOME` System variable to a value of `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0`(My computer is running on **windows 7** Home basic).

I have started up the server by **startup.bat** file in `bin` folder. When I just try to access `localhost:8080`, it always says `unable to connect` on the browser. So I changed the port number to `9999` in **server.xml** and restarted it. It again says unable to connect in my browser. When I start up the server it shows the following on the command shell. Can someone please help me solve this issue and make my server work?

By observing the following on the command shell, I could only find this line which seems to give some indication of the problem: **`Failed to initialize component [Standard Server[8005]]`**. I still don't know what it has to do with the unable to connect..

```
Feb 24, 2013 4:58:02 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener init
INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performanc
e in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: C:\Program
Files\Java\jdk1.6.0\bin;.;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\system32;C:\
Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\
Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0\bin
Feb 24, 2013 4:58:02 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
SEVERE: Catalina.start
org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to initialize component [Standard
Server[8005]]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:106)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:633)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:658)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.
java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAcces
sorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:585)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.load(Bootstrap.java:281)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:455)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to initialize componen
t [StandardService[Catalina]]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:106)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.initInternal(StandardServer.j
ava:814)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:102)
        ... 8 more
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to initialize componen
t [StandardEngine[Catalina]]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:106)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.initInternal(StandardService
.java:544)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:102)
        ... 10 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.
allowCoreThreadTimeOut(Z)V
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.initInternal(ContainerBase.jav
a:1083)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.initInternal(StandardEngine.j
ava:283)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:102)
        ... 12 more
Feb 24, 2013 4:58:02 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 532 ms
Feb 24, 2013 4:58:02 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol pause
INFO: Pausing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-9999"]
Feb 24, 2013 4:58:02 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol pause
INFO: Pausing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
Feb 24, 2013 4:58:02 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService stopInternal
INFO: Stopping service Catalina
Feb 24, 2013 4:58:03 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
SEVERE: Catalina.start:
org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to stop component [StandardServer
[8005]]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.stop(LifecycleBase.java:236)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:141)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:684)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.
java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAcces
sorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:585)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:322)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:456)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: An invalid Lifecycle transiti
on was attempted ([before_stop]) for component [org.apache.catalina.deploy.Namin
gResources@1807ca8] in state [INITIALIZED]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.invalidTransition(LifecycleBas
e.java:409)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.stop(LifecycleBase.java:219)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.stopInternal(StandardServer.j
ava:756)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.stop(LifecycleBase.java:232)
        ... 8 more
Feb 24, 2013 4:58:03 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 11 ms
```

Comment: Do you have any older Java versions on your system? What does `java -version` show?

Comment: Have you changed any other config files? Do you have a backup of the config file you changed? Tomcat usually works out of the box, and changing config is not recommended for a beginner.

Comment: @LukeTaylor No, I don't have any older java versions. I have java 1.6.

Comment: @NickJ Yeah. I have back up.

Answer (score 0):

One thing I noticed it the stack trace is this:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.allowCoreThreadTimeOut(Z)V
```

Looking at the Javadoc for ThreadPoolExecutor, it appears that the method allowCoreThreatTimeOut(boolean) was introduced in Java 6. It was not present in earlier versions. The error above is exactly what you'd find if you run a java program designed for version 6+ on an out-of-date JVM.

When you first start tomcat, you should have lines something like this:

```
Using CATALINA_BASE:   /home/nick/tools/apache-tomcat-6.0.35
Using CATALINA_HOME:   /home/nick/tools/apache-tomcat-6.0.35
Using CATALINA_TMPDIR: /home/nick/tools/apache-tomcat-6.0.35/temp
Using JRE_HOME:        /usr
Using CLASSPATH:       /home/nick/tools/apache-tomcat-6.0.35/bin/bootstrap.jar
```

Look at the directory for JRE_HOME and see what you get. Maybe you have a Java 5 installed somewhere which Tomcat's trying to use, although the command line sees the Java 6 installation. Having multiple java versions installed can cause confusion.

Answer (score 0):

Tomcat needs JRE as env.
Then start the tomcat.
or set the path for JRE_HOME in "catalina.bat" file.
Find the attached screenshot
[image]